# Actionscript & jQuery function integration

Tags: jquery, actionscript

I would like to call a jQuery pager function (p) defined as:

```
function p(page)
    {
        $('#pitch').load(page);
    }
```

how can I call this function inner swf with method getURL..

note: normally I call it in html tag as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="p('somefile.php?id=someid');">link name</a>
```

Comment: you use externalInterface class in AS3

Comment: unfortunately I'm dealing with AS2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the externalInterface class provided by default like follows:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call("javascriptFunction", param1, param2);
```

now here the javascript function could be your defined function i.e p(as in code above) , or you can sirectly pass the string $('#pitch').load and pass the parameter pageas string.

Comment: Is there any posibility handle this in AS2?

Comment: you can use almos the same functions... check it out here http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html